# Nginx request headers empty when using docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

Request headers are net getting set when using a docker container

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.23.3-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

nginx.conf

```
events{}
http {
    map "$http_abc" $abc{}
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        location / {
            add_header Set-Cookie "abc=$abc; Path=/;";
        }
    }
}
```

Docker build/run

```
docker build -f ./Dockerfile . -t abc
docker run -d -p 8888:80  --name competent_swirles abc
```

Curl command to test

```
curl localhost:8888 -H "abc:123" --verbose
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with map, it's not meant to be used like this.
What you want is [set](https://Sets%20a%20value%20for%20the%20specified%20variable), to copy the value of `$http_abc` to `$abc`.

For example :

```
events{}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        location / {
            set $abc $http_abc;
            add_header Set-Cookie "abc=$abc; Path=/;";           
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you want you can use `$http_abc` directly :

```
add_header Set-Cookie "abc=$http_abc; Path=/;";
```

Hope this helps !